# How to root a Huawei G330D (U8825D) phone?

Tags: rooting

The Huawei U8825D is on Android 4.0.4, and my computer is on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: You might want to check the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), follow it up to [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575), go to the section titled "Methods/apps", and take a look at available methods, especially [Root Many Android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460) which should work for many ICS/JB devices. If you succeeded, please answer your own question with details on the steps required. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some Windows machine you could use for 10 minutes.
Follow this tutorial and you'll be good:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=31986973&postcount=21
**Unlocking Bootloader**
1) download the following file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfhdbykms3imxr4/G330D%20a%20key%20to%20unlock.rar

2) go to Settings>Application>Fast boot and "click off"

3) power off the phone (to make sure pull out the battery about 5 seconds after switch off)

4) enter to the fastboot mode by pressing (Volume Down + Power Button) about 15 seconds and connect cable to the computer

5) double click and open >> G330D一键解锁.exe file form unlock folder that you downloaded

6) type the unlock code that you got form Huawei official website and press 
if you didn't yet, here is Huawei official website to unlock bootloader (it is easy to follow in English version) >>>http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/servicePolicy.do?method=toApplyUnlock

7) it will automatically restart and your bootloader successfully unlocked 


**Install CWM**
1) download the following file -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/61a0e0553cu7wwt/recovery6.0.1.2_AscendG330D.rar

2) power off and pull out battery about 5 second

3) enter to the fastboot mode by pressing Volume Down + Power Button about 15 seconds and connect cable to the computer 

4) run this recovery6.0.1.2_AscendG330D.exe file that you got from downloaded zip file.

5) there will be see in China Lungaue in cmd. Actually, I don't know what  but type 1 and press enter

6) enter again

7) it will be reboot automatically and successfully installed CWM

8) to go to the CWM recovery, press Volume Up + Power Button after power off



**ROOT**
1) download the following file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ytam587dakpdp9/Root%20Recovery.zip

2) copy the downloaded "Root Recovery.zip" file to the SD card 

3) go to recovery and Install zip from SD card

4) after reboot system, successfully rooted your phone.

Comment: What are you talking about? It works just fine. I just checked all the mentioned links on the website, and every single link works. But I edited my answer so that it'll be available here.

Comment: My point is: Answers on Stack Exchange are expected to be self-contained. An answer that is just a link elsewhere is not an answer.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thank you for your helpful review. That helps me improve my future answers :)